# In the AWS linux terminal every time I run the history command the numbering changes

Tags: bash, command-history

This makes it impossible to reference previous commands by number.

```shellsession
$ history | tail -3
 6691  git push -f
 6692  history
 6693  history | tail -3
s4dad\patrant@a-48265ltymm4y:~/eyp-source/d8 (feature/EYP-12393-add-results-date-as-a-round-parameter =)
$ history | tail -3
 6740  git push -f
 6741  history
 6742  history | tail -3
s4dad\patrant@a-48265ltymm4y:~/eyp-source/d8 (feature/EYP-12393-add-results-date-as-a-round-parameter =)
$ history | tail -3
 6789  git push -f
 6790  history
 6791  history | tail -3
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be fixed?

Comment: How is the terminal window that displays on your screen connected to the machine that's running AWS Linux?  Via the AWS Console Web UI?  An ssh command to the machine from your laptop/desktop computer running Linux/MacOS/Windows?

Comment: It's the terminal running in the AWS GUI, in the AWS client.

Comment: Does an ordinary ssh connection (e.g., from another AWS server in the same VPC/subnet) show the same jumps in the command history?

Comment: I ssh-ed to my own account. The problem is still there, albeit the jump is much smaller (9 numbers instead of 49).